# How to remove token from sap.m.MultiInput control and only text should be shown?

Tags: sapui5

I want to remove the token button from the `sap.m.MultiInput` control. Only the text and other functions should be there. Can anyone please help me on how to disable the token button and make it so that only the text should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

It you want to remove the delete icon from the individual tokens, you will have to set the individual token's `editable` property to `false`.

To do this in a MultiInput control, you will have to look-up it's tokens-aggregation and iterate through them to switch them all to non-editable:

```
var multiInput = this.getView().byId("multiInput");
var tokens = multiInput.getTokens();
jQuery.each(tokens, function(idx, token) {
    token.setEditable(false);
});
```